# Algorithm Recurrence Relation

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

How is the following recurrence relation solved:

```
T(n) = 2T(n-2)+O(1)
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
O(1) is lower or equal than a constant c.
```

So

```
 T(n) <= 2T(n-2) + c
 T(n) <= 4T(n-4) + 2c
 T(n) <= 8T(n-6) + 3c
          .
          .
          .
```

So a pattern is emerging... the general term is:

```
T(n) <= 2^k*T(n-2k) + kc
```

But I dont know how to continue from there.Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It's maybe not the right Stack site to post. Guys from Computer Science site would help you more.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be ontopic. You might be able to get help on the Computer Science site.

Comment: Ok I will ask there

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your generalization for `k` is true<sup>[1]</sup>

```
T(n) <= 2^k*T(n-2k) + kc
```

For `k=n/2` you get:

```
T(n) <= 2^n/2 * T(0) + n/2 * c = 2^(n/2) + n/2*c
```

Which is in `O(sqrt(2^n))`

Formal proof can be done with induction, with the induction hypothesis of:

```
T(n) <= 2^(n/2) + c*n
```

And step of:

```
T(n) = 2T(n-2) + c  = (induction hypothesis)
T(n) = 2* 2^((n-2)/2)  + (n-2)*c + c
T(n) = 2^ (n/2 - 2/2 + 1) + (n-1)*c
And indeed: 
T(n) = 2^(n/2) + (n-1)*c <= 2^(n/2) + c*n
```

---

(1) It is not, it ignores the fact that the constant is multiplied in the loop.